# How can Microsoft team automatically do outgoing webhook?

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams

I am developing MS teams bot.

I am creating a function to send a webhook automatically when I receive a message.

The development was carried out by referring to the URL below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook

Like the URL above, teams support outgoing webbook.
However, the outgoing webbook must manually enter @mention in the chat window for the bot to work.

I want to tag @mention automatically when I receive a message
Is there a way to do a webhook?

Even if it's not an outgoing webbook,
The robot or ms flow can receive messages and send messages automatically.
I want to develop a robot.

You also need to provide that bot for use by multiple teams.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can automatically sync all messages in a channel. But you can use the graph API to constantly check the channel for new messages and pull them into your service.[Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/teams-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can [subscribe to notifications for Microsoft Teams](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/blogs/announcing-change-notifications-for-microsoft-teams-messages/) messages. This feature is available in beta on the Microsoft Graph API.